# Unable to download the App from Google play store it shows Authentication error

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I am unable to download App from google play store, it shows authentication error.

But I have signed in to my Google accounts.

Attached is the screen shot.

Please help me on the issue, unable to find the thread.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution on my question. posting it for the users who will face the issue in future.

It is because of the Google Play store new policy of content rating.

If you upload any App on the store, you need to Answer the questionnaires for the content used in the App.

This is used by Google to determine the content used in the App and show it to the users based on the content policy and Age validation.

Hence, if you are uploading any new App or updating an existing App on store. Do follow the content rating steps
[link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en)

After following this I was able to download the App from store.

Happy coding !!